# How can I save data to a web.config file?

Tags: asp.net

How can I save data from a text box control to a web.config file?

Comment: This is the wrong place for this kind of question.  (Besides, it is too lacking in detail to be answerable.)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to do that.

Every time the web.config is modifed, the App_Pool is recycled. Not good for your users, since that dumps all session information.

Probably not what you want.

You can save the data in ASP.NET Session State, and create an SQL Server instance to hold the session state information. Or you can hold it in ViewState if it's not long lived.

Really, to answer your question we need to know the purpose of this data, and how long it's expected to live.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Item("Key").Value = TextBox1.Text;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```